# PHP & Init script

Tags: php, init.d

I've written a php job handler for mediawiki. The script will spawn 4 PHP processes (Scanner, and three workers).

```
youri@pewpew:~$ ps -aux | grep php
www-data  1579  0.5  0.2 263888 12752 ?        SN   Feb19  38:44 php Scanner.ph
www-data  1581  0.0  0.2 263612 12656 ?        SN   Feb19   6:29 php Worker.php
www-data  1594  0.0  0.2 263612 12652 ?        SN   Feb19   6:13 php Worker.php
www-data  1597  0.0  0.2 263612 12652 ?        SN   Feb19   6:08 php Worker.php
youri     1961  0.0  0.0   9360   660 pts/0    R+   11:48   0:00 grep --color=auto php
```

The processes are started with a start.php file:

```
#!/usr/bin/php 
<?php

require_once('config.php');

$logger->log('Starting scanner');
exec("nice -n 10 php Scanner.php > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &");

$logger->log('Starting workers');
for ($i = 0; $i < $config->getMaxRunningJobs(); $i++) { 
    exec("nice -n 10 php Worker.php > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &");
    sleep(1);
}

$logger->log('Done');
```

What is the best way to add this to a init script (since it has no stop/status)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write a standard init script with `php start.php` as the start function.

As for the stop function do something like:

```
kill -9 `ps -ef|grep "php Scanner.php"|awk '{ print $2 }'`
```

And you can leave the status function empty.

Comment: Hi Jos, thank you for your quick answer. What is the best way to stop the running processes? Look them up with ps -aux?

Comment: Yes, I added that to the answer.

Comment: I think the processes will be the script's children, so if you can keep track of the script's PID, then `pkill -P <script-PID>` would be the cleanest.